# Best approach to simplify phantom array logic (ERC721 Enumerable) [HARD]

Tags: nft, erc-721, optimization, data, hack

I wanted to create an `ERC721` token vault with arbitrary numbers of NFTs pre-"minted", yet compliant with `IERC721Enumerable` as a proof-of-concept.

For simplicity, the NFT ids are contiguous. When a token is 'bought' it is removed from the token vault and sent to a standard `(address => uint[])` mapping.

#### Approach:

Use a virtual bi-directional mapping where default values are mapped to phantom array indices (until they are overwritten).

Once this approach is perfected it's trivial to adapt it to `IERC721Enumerable`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.21;

contract PhantomIndex {
   
    // We use the same data-pattern for arrays in storage, but the values are virtual.
    // Action 1: remove value 5 from phantom array
    // phantom array: [0,1,2,3,4,5, 6,7,8,9,10] (length 11)
    // (swap places): [0,1,2,3,4,10,6,7,8,9,5]  (length 11)
    // (remove last): [0,1,2,3,4,10,6,7,8,9]    (length 10)
    // Action 2: remove value 10 from phantom array
    //              : [0,1,2,3,4,10,6,7,8,9]    (length 10)
    //              : [0,1,2,3,4,9,6,7,8,10]    (length 10)
    //              : [0,1,2,3,4,9,6,7,8]       (length 9)

    // Phantom Indexes are contiguous: 0 to arbitrary

    /// @dev Implementation:
    mapping (uint tokenID => uint index) public tokenToIndex;
    mapping (uint index => uint tokenID) public indexToToken;
    mapping (uint => bool) public isBought;

    uint public virtualLength = 11; // arbitrary, can be 2 million.

    // tokenToIndex[0] = 0          // indexToTokenID[0] = 0
    // tokenToIndex[1] = 0          // indexToTokenID[1] = 0
    // tokenToIndex[2] = 0 (etc)    // indexToTokenID[2] = 0

    // This is admittedly VERY hacky. This implementation does NOT work with zero at the moment.
    function removeFromPhantomIndex(uint tokenID) public {
        if (isBought[tokenID]) { revert("ERC721: Token already bought from vault.");}

        // make the new token index the last position.
        uint lastIndex = virtualLength - 1;

        // what's the current index of this token?
        uint lastStoredIndex = tokenToIndex[tokenID];
        
        // now, what's the current token stored at the last virtual index? 
        uint tokenAtLastIndex = indexToToken[lastIndex];

        // if currentIndex is 0, tokenID IS the index;
        // ERROR when 0
        if (lastStoredIndex == 0) {
            tokenToIndex[tokenID] = lastStoredIndex = tokenID; // example: tokenToIndex[2] = (2) = 2;
        }

        if (tokenAtLastIndex == 0) {
            // if token at last index is 0, lastIndex IS the tokenID
            indexToToken[lastIndex] = tokenAtLastIndex = lastIndex;
        }

        tokenToIndex[tokenAtLastIndex] = lastStoredIndex;
        indexToToken[lastStoredIndex] = tokenAtLastIndex;

        tokenToIndex[tokenID] = lastIndex; // example: tokenToIndex[5] = 10
        indexToToken[lastIndex] = tokenID; // example: indexToToken[10] = 5 
        
        isBought[tokenID] = true;

        --virtualLength;
    }


    function getPhantomUINTs() public view returns (uint[] memory uints) {
        uints = new uint[](virtualLength);
        for (uint i; i < virtualLength; ++i) {
            uints[i] = phantomIndexAt(i);
        }
    }

    function phantomIndexAt(uint index) public view returns (uint tokenID) {
        if (index >= virtualLength) { revert("ERC721: Invalid index."); }

        tokenID = indexToToken[index];

        return (tokenID == 0) ? index : tokenID;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's still not simpler, but it works as an implementation:

```
/// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.21;

contract PhantomIndex {

    address payable public immutable THIS;
    constructor() {
        THIS = payable(address(this));
    }

    // We use the same data-pattern for arrays in storage, but the values are virtual
    // Phantom Indexes are contiguous: 1 to arbitrary
    // Update: Removed 0 as valid tokenID. Added offset to ensure no lookup collisions.
    // using offset 2000:

    // tokenToIndex[2000] = 0          // indexToTokenID[0] = 0 => (2000)
    // tokenToIndex[2001] = 0          // indexToTokenID[1] = 0 => (2001)
    // tokenToIndex[2002] = 0 (etc)    // indexToTokenID[2] = 0 => (2002)

    error ERC721InvalidIndex(uint index);
    error ERC721InvalidId(uint tokenID);

    mapping (address => uint[]) public balances;
    mapping (uint => address) public owners;

    mapping (uint t => uint BooleanUINT) public isBoughtFromTokenVault;
    mapping (uint tokenID => uint index) public tokenToIndex;
    mapping (uint index => uint tokenID) public indexToToken;

    uint constant TRUE = 2; 
    uint constant FALSE = 0;

    uint constant offset = 1; // minimum offset 1.

    uint public constant InitialNFTSupply = 10;
    uint public length = InitialNFTSupply+1; // vaultTokenLength

    // It's still not simpler, sadly :/ , but it is now functional:
    function removeFromPhantomIndex(uint tokenID) public {
        require(length > 0 && offset > 0);
        if ((tokenID < offset) || (tokenID > (offset + InitialNFTSupply))) { revert ERC721InvalidId(tokenID); }
        if (isBoughtFromTokenVault[tokenID] == TRUE) { revert("ERC721: Token already bought from vault.");}

        // get the last valid index of of the mapping(s).
        uint lastIndex = (length - 1) + offset;

        // what's the current stored index of this token?
        uint currentIndex = tokenToIndex[tokenID];

        // if currentIndex is 0, tokenID IS the index;
        // since we're setting both simultaneously, if one value is unset the other value also is.

        if (currentIndex == 0) {
            tokenToIndex[tokenID] = currentIndex = tokenID; // example: tokenToIndex[1] = (1) = 1;
            // indexToToken[tokenID] = tokenID;
        }

        // now, what's the current tokenID stored at the last virtual index? 
        uint tokenIDAtLastIndex = indexToToken[lastIndex];

        // if token at last index is 0, lastIndex IS the tokenID
        if (tokenIDAtLastIndex == 0) {
            indexToToken[lastIndex] = tokenIDAtLastIndex = lastIndex; //+ offset);
        }

        tokenToIndex[tokenIDAtLastIndex] = currentIndex;
        indexToToken[currentIndex] = tokenIDAtLastIndex;

        tokenToIndex[tokenID] = lastIndex; // example: tokenToIndex[5] = 10
        indexToToken[lastIndex] = tokenID; // example: indexToToken[10] = 5 
        
        isBoughtFromTokenVault[tokenID] = TRUE;

        --length; // it reverts from -- length.
    }


    function getPhantomUINTs() public view returns (uint[] memory nfts) {
        nfts = new uint[](length);
        for (uint i; i < length; ++i) { nfts[i] = VaultTokenAt(i); }
    }
 
    function VaultTokenAt(uint index) public view returns (uint tokenID) {
        if (index >= length) { revert ERC721InvalidIndex(index); }
        index += offset;
        tokenID = indexToToken[index]; // defaults to zero
        return (tokenID != 0) ? tokenID : index;
    }


    /*
     * See {IERC721Enumerable-tokenOfOwnerByIndex}
     */
    function tokenOfOwnerByIndex(address account, uint index) external view returns (uint) {
        return (account == address(this)) ? VaultTokenAt(index) : balances[account][index];
    }
  
}
```